# sliding window with priority sampling

Tags: python-2.7, sliding-window

I have a python list and I need to create from this a sliding window with priority sampling.
In specific,the list(created from a json file) is the following:

> print jfile['id']=>

```
445860938797707000
445860940027006000
445860940144463000
445860940907819000
445860941289492000
445860942677803000
445860943072067000
445860944347136000
445860944791740000
445860944778768000
```

the code i use for the sliding window is:

```
numData=100

stream1=np.random.random(numData)
```

`def prioritySampling (stream, sampleSize):`

```
sample=np.zeros(sampleSize)
tags=np.zeros(sampleSize)

i=0
j=0
while i<len(stream):
    if i<sampleSize:
        sample[i] = stream[i]
        tags[i] = np.random.random()
    else:
        newTag = np.random.random()
        maxTag = np.max(tags)
        idxMaxTag = np.argmax(tags)

        if maxTag > newTag:
            sample[idxMaxTag]=stream[i]
            tags[idxMaxTag]=newTag
            j=j+1
    i=i+1
print 'updates priority=',j    
return sample


sampleP1 = prioritySampling (stream1, 10)

p1 = np.array (sampleP1)
```

This works fine in random numbers.
What if I need to use the list as I showed before?
Bear in mind that the list originally has about 35.000 ids and I want to have in the end the 10 most popular ids.
That is, that some ids are presented many times

Comment: hi guys,are there any ideas about this?

Comment: anyone? any ideas?